# Holder onClick() taking action on wrong rows

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-viewholder

I have an Custom ArrayAdapter for a listview that has multiple buttons. But when i click a button in a row its action with wrong row. Example; when i clicked first row's button, it click action is working for another row.

getView  codes here:

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    this.position = position * 2;

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_galery2_list, parent, false);
        holder = new Holder(view);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {

        holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
    }

    ((TextView) view.findViewWithTag("textView1")).setText(list
            .get(this.position).yazi.toString());
    ((TextView) view.findViewWithTag("textView2")).setText(list
            .get(this.position + 1).yazi.toString());


    holder.getImage1().setImageBitmap((list.get(this.position).image));
    holder.getImage2().setImageBitmap((list.get(this.position + 1).image));




    final Holder h1 = holder;
    holder.btn_follow1().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (h1.btn_follow1().getBackground().getConstantState()==
                    context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.followoff).getConstantState())  {
                h1.btn_follow1().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.followon);

            } else if(h1.btn_follow1().getBackground().getConstantState()==
                    context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.followon).getConstantState())  {
                h1.btn_follow1().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.followoff);

                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
    });
```

class holder codes here:

```
    public class Holder {

    private View row;
    private ImageView img_img;
    private ImageView img_img2;
    private Button btn_follow1;
    private Button btn_follow2;


    public Holder(View row) {
        this.row = row;
    }

    public ImageView getImage1() {
        if (img_img == null) {
            img_img = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.img_img1);
        }
        return img_img;
    }

    public ImageView getImage2() {
        if (img_img2 == null) {
            img_img2 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.img_img2);
        }
        return img_img2;
    }

    public Button btn_follow1() {
        if (btn_follow1 == null) {
            btn_follow1 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_follow1);
        }
        return btn_follow1;
    }

    public Button btn_follow2() {
        if (btn_follow2 == null) {
            btn_follow2 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_follow2);
        }
        return btn_follow2;
    }
}
```

whats best way to fix this problem?

edit:

when i clicked first row's follow button;

before clicked:[image]

and after clicked [image]

Comment: first - what's the purpose of this : this.position = position * 2
and second - could you see some pattern, define the function from the item clicked on to the item actually reacting ?

Comment: hmm, i have two list in an activity. my lists working like gridview. position = position*2 is fot it.   i checked

Comment: so when you click on row 1, 2, 3 etc it always reacts as row 0 ? and what happens when you click on row 0 ?

Comment: in any case, the position modification is really not a good trick. ListView is somewhat rigid to begin with, and meddling with it this way doesnt seem very healthy - even if you think it works, sounds like it may well be related.

Comment: seems like she/he is tring to emulate GridView ... anyway i will post the link 3rd time this day but ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70 < watch and learn about convertView ... basically: some reused view has already background set to off/on(and you do not reset it in getView) ... anyway it is done all wrong ... use some ArrayList<Integer> to indicate the position of "checked" item and in getView check if position exists in this array and if exists select background ... then on click of button only add the position to the array(notifyDataSetChanged will cause getView called)

Comment: array can be also replaced with isfollow field inside your item model ... in on click you set it to true/false and in getView you should choose the background based on this field ...

Comment: +1 @Selvin for the isFollow field.

Answer (score 0):

Its because `this.position = position * 2;`. Hence :

- Position 0 (first) is still 0
- Position 1 become 2
- Position 2 become 4
- and its going on

You might want to reconsider how you manage the `position` variable. In **normal** situation (ex : if user click position 0, position 0 will activated), you dont need to do anything with `position`.

Comment: thanks for helping but it isnt problem. i checked already position. when  i clicked buttons positions working well, when i clicked first row,  anothers rows working with first row actions. i think problem about with holder's row..